# Android android.view.InflateException Binary XML file line #644: Error inflating class <unknown>?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, logcat

I don't know how to fix this error, first the app works great, it starts opening a menu then I press a button to start a new class and it works fine but when I press the back button and select it again it the application stops working. so any idea how to fix this problem?

line #644:

```
<ImageButton     //<<this is line 644
       android:id="@+id/sephiroth"
       android:layout_width="110dip"
       android:layout_height="110dip"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:background="@android:color/transparent"
       android:scaleType="fitCenter"
       android:src="@drawable/sephiroth" />
```

here is my logcat:

```
08-11 17:19:39.758: D/dalvikvm(2108): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3146K, 9% free 55441K/60568K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
08-11 17:19:39.788: D/dalvikvm(2108): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 16761K, 35% free 39783K/60568K, paused 0ms, total 0ms
08-11 17:19:39.808: D/dalvikvm(2108): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 257K, 33% free 40653K/60568K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
08-11 17:19:39.818: D/dalvikvm(2108): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 159K, 31% free 42392K/60568K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
08-11 17:19:39.848: D/dalvikvm(2108): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 383K, 28% free 43924K/60568K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
08-11 17:19:39.868: D/dalvikvm(2108): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 27% free 44719K/60568K, paused 4ms, total 4ms
08-11 17:19:39.868: I/dalvikvm-heap(2108): Grow heap (frag case) to 46.997MB for 3256332-byte allocation
08-11 17:19:39.898: D/dalvikvm(2108): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 21% free 47899K/60568K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
08-11 17:19:39.938: D/dalvikvm(2108): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 968K, 20% free 48480K/60568K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
08-11 17:19:39.948: D/dalvikvm(2108): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 670K, 19% free 49199K/60568K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
08-11 17:19:39.968: D/dalvikvm(2108): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 195K, 17% free 50697K/60568K, paused 0ms, total 0ms
08-11 17:19:39.988: D/dalvikvm(2108): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 900K, 16% free 51409K/60568K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
08-11 17:19:40.008: D/dalvikvm(2108): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 14% free 52356K/60568K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
08-11 17:19:40.028: D/dalvikvm(2108): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1011K, 12% free 53360K/60568K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
08-11 17:19:40.058: D/dalvikvm(2108): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 290K, 10% free 54990K/60568K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
08-11 17:19:40.078: D/dalvikvm(2108): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 456K, 8% free 55962K/60568K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
08-11 17:19:40.098: D/dalvikvm(2108): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 606K, 7% free 56434K/60568K, paused 4ms, total 4ms
08-11 17:19:40.118: D/dalvikvm(2108): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 6% free 57536K/60568K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
08-11 17:19:40.118: I/dalvikvm-heap(2108): Grow heap (frag case) to 58.319MB for 2004096-byte allocation
08-11 17:19:40.138: D/dalvikvm(2108): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 5% free 59493K/62528K, paused 12ms, total 12ms
08-11 17:19:40.168: D/dalvikvm(2108): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1102K, 6% free 59012K/62528K, paused 2ms, total 3ms
08-11 17:19:40.168: I/dalvikvm-heap(2108): Grow heap (frag case) to 60.268MB for 2537276-byte allocation
08-11 17:19:40.188: D/dalvikvm(2108): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 6% free 61490K/65008K, paused 5ms, total 5ms
08-11 17:19:40.208: D/dalvikvm(2108): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 619K, 6% free 61616K/65008K, paused 3ms, total 4ms
08-11 17:19:40.208: I/dalvikvm-heap(2108): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 1336152-byte allocation
08-11 17:19:40.218: D/dalvikvm(2108): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 9K, 6% free 61606K/65008K, paused 7ms, total 8ms
08-11 17:19:40.218: E/dalvikvm-heap(2108): Out of memory on a 1336152-byte allocation.
08-11 17:19:40.218: I/dalvikvm(2108): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
08-11 17:19:40.218: I/dalvikvm(2108):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0xb0e8e480 self=0xb96e91e0
08-11 17:19:40.218: I/dalvikvm(2108):   | sysTid=2108 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[fopen-error:2] handle=-1217351648
08-11 17:19:40.218: I/dalvikvm(2108):   | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=141 stm=171 core=0
08-11 17:19:40.218: I/dalvikvm(2108):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
08-11 17:19:40.218: I/dalvikvm(2108):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:503)
08-11 17:19:40.218: I/dalvikvm(2108):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:356)
08-11 17:19:40.218: I/dalvikvm(2108):   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:800)
08-11 17:19:40.218: I/dalvikvm(2108):   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2105)
08-11 17:19:40.218: I/dalvikvm(2108):   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
08-11 17:19:40.218: I/dalvikvm(2108):   at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:127)
08-11 17:19:40.218: I/dalvikvm(2108):   at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:87)
08-11 17:19:40.228: I/dalvikvm(2108):   at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:83)
08-11 17:19:40.228: I/dalvikvm(2108):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
08-11 17:19:40.228: I/dalvikvm(2108):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
08-11 17:19:40.228: I/dalvikvm(2108):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
08-11 17:19:40.228: I/dalvikvm(2108):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
08-11 17:19:40.228: I/dalvikvm(2108):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
08-11 17:19:40.228: I/dalvikvm(2108):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
08-11 17:19:40.228: I/dalvikvm(2108):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
08-11 17:19:40.228: I/dalvikvm(2108):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
08-11 17:19:40.228: I/dalvikvm(2108):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
08-11 17:19:40.228: I/dalvikvm(2108):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
08-11 17:19:40.228: I/dalvikvm(2108):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
08-11 17:19:40.228: I/dalvikvm(2108):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
08-11 17:19:40.228: I/dalvikvm(2108):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
08-11 17:19:40.228: I/dalvikvm(2108):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
08-11 17:19:40.228: I/dalvikvm(2108):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
08-11 17:19:40.228: I/dalvikvm(2108):   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
08-11 17:19:40.228: I/dalvikvm(2108):   at com.shattereddimension.khguide.kh2fm.onCreate(kh2fm.java:29)
08-11 17:19:40.228: I/dalvikvm(2108):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
08-11 17:19:40.228: I/dalvikvm(2108):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
08-11 17:19:40.228: I/dalvikvm(2108):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
08-11 17:19:40.228: I/dalvikvm(2108):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
08-11 17:19:40.228: I/dalvikvm(2108):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-11 17:19:40.228: I/dalvikvm(2108):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
08-11 17:19:40.228: I/dalvikvm(2108):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-11 17:19:40.228: I/dalvikvm(2108):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-11 17:19:40.228: I/dalvikvm(2108):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
08-11 17:19:40.228: I/dalvikvm(2108):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-11 17:19:40.228: I/dalvikvm(2108):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-11 17:19:40.228: I/dalvikvm(2108):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
08-11 17:19:40.228: I/dalvikvm(2108):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-11 17:19:40.228: I/dalvikvm(2108):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-11 17:19:40.228: D/skia(2108): --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
08-11 17:19:40.228: D/AndroidRuntime(2108): Shutting down VM
08-11 17:19:40.228: W/dalvikvm(2108): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb0e8d648)
08-11 17:19:40.228: E/AndroidRuntime(2108): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-11 17:19:40.228: E/AndroidRuntime(2108): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.shattereddimension.khguide/com.shattereddimension.khguide.kh2fm}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #644: Error inflating class <unknown>
08-11 17:19:40.228: E/AndroidRuntime(2108):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
08-11 17:19:40.228: E/AndroidRuntime(2108):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
08-11 17:19:40.228: E/AndroidRuntime(2108):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-11 17:19:40.228: E/AndroidRuntime(2108):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
08-11 17:19:40.228: E/AndroidRuntime(2108):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-11 17:19:40.228: E/AndroidRuntime(2108):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-11 17:19:40.228: E/AndroidRuntime(2108):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
08-11 17:19:40.228: E/AndroidRuntime(2108):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-11 17:19:40.228: E/AndroidRuntime(2108):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-11 17:19:40.228: E/AndroidRuntime(2108):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
08-11 17:19:40.228: E/AndroidRuntime(2108):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-11 17:19:40.228: E/AndroidRuntime(2108):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-11 17:19:40.228: E/AndroidRuntime(2108): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #644: Error inflating class <unknown>
08-11 17:19:40.228: E/AndroidRuntime(2108):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
08-11 17:19:40.228: E/AndroidRuntime(2108):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
08-11 17:19:40.228: E/AndroidRuntime(2108):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
08-11 17:19:40.228: E/AndroidRuntime(2108):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
08-11 17:19:40.228: E/AndroidRuntime(2108):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
08-11 17:19:40.228: E/AndroidRuntime(2108):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
08-11 17:19:40.228: E/AndroidRuntime(2108):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
08-11 17:19:40.228: E/AndroidRuntime(2108):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
08-11 17:19:40.228: E/AndroidRuntime(2108):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
08-11 17:19:40.228: E/AndroidRuntime(2108):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
08-11 17:19:40.228: E/AndroidRuntime(2108):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
08-11 17:19:40.228: E/AndroidRuntime(2108):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
08-11 17:19:40.228: E/AndroidRuntime(2108):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
08-11 17:19:40.228: E/AndroidRuntime(2108):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
08-11 17:19:40.228: E/AndroidRuntime(2108):     at com.shattereddimension.khguide.kh2fm.onCreate(kh2fm.java:29)
08-11 17:19:40.228: E/AndroidRuntime(2108):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
08-11 17:19:40.228: E/AndroidRuntime(2108):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
08-11 17:19:40.228: E/AndroidRuntime(2108):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
08-11 17:19:40.228: E/AndroidRuntime(2108):     ... 11 more
08-11 17:19:40.228: E/AndroidRuntime(2108): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
08-11 17:19:40.228: E/AndroidRuntime(2108):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
08-11 17:19:40.228: E/AndroidRuntime(2108):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
08-11 17:19:40.228: E/AndroidRuntime(2108):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
08-11 17:19:40.228: E/AndroidRuntime(2108):     ... 28 more
08-11 17:19:40.228: E/AndroidRuntime(2108): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
08-11 17:19:40.228: E/AndroidRuntime(2108):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
08-11 17:19:40.228: E/AndroidRuntime(2108):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:503)
08-11 17:19:40.228: E/AndroidRuntime(2108):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:356)
08-11 17:19:40.228: E/AndroidRuntime(2108):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:800)
08-11 17:19:40.228: E/AndroidRuntime(2108):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2105)
08-11 17:19:40.228: E/AndroidRuntime(2108):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
08-11 17:19:40.228: E/AndroidRuntime(2108):     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:127)
08-11 17:19:40.228: E/AndroidRuntime(2108):     at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:87)
08-11 17:19:40.228: E/AndroidRuntime(2108):     at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:83)
08-11 17:19:40.228: E/AndroidRuntime(2108):     ... 31 more
```

Comment: Please post the code used by your activity, which is failing with the message of "Unable to start activity ComponentInfo"?

Comment: **"Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError"** : As answered by user3586222, you've run out of memory. I have to admit when I saw you had a layout file with 644 lines (or more) I thought it was a bit strange - I've never had a layout file with more than about 50 or 60 lines of code. You're going to need to manage your images better.

Comment: I'am using picasso for the images, and they are 20 images with 30 textviews and this is the smallest thing I could do write know

Comment: @user3896367 : I can only guess that you're re-running the code which original loaded the images and it's attempting to re-load them without releasing the resources (memory) used by the first load operation. Look at changing how you load them.

Comment: how do i release the memory? @Squonk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real reason is OOM(Out of Memory),not inflating problem.

```
08-11 17:19:40.218: D/dalvikvm(2108): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 9K, 6% free 61606K/65008K, paused 7ms, total 8ms
08-11 17:19:40.218: E/dalvikvm-heap(2108): Out of memory on a 1336152-byte allocation.
08-11 17:19:40.218: I/dalvikvm(2108): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
```

because when start a new activity and inflating layout,it need some memory to init views like Button、ImageButton、ImageView、custom view and so on.but because of OOM,there hasn't enough space for init these views,so the android system throws exception.

to solve this problem:you may find the reason cause oom and fix it,and i advise you close android hardwareAccelerated if you needn't it to save space.like this:

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
<activity ... />
<activity android:hardwareAccelerated="false" />
</application>
```

more info about how to solve this problem：[Performance Tips](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html)

sorry for my poor english,feel free to ask me!

Comment: is there any other solution than the hardwareAccelerated

Comment: Please click the link and see more solutaion [link](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html)

Answer (score 0):

This

```
08-11 17:19:40.218: E/dalvikvm-heap(2108): Out of memory on a 1336152-byte allocation.
08-11 17:19:40.218: I/dalvikvm(2108): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
```

That error is because your image is to big, the best thing is reduce his size.

Comment: the image size is 400x400

Comment: Are you sure that is the only image?

Comment: all of them are is this range they are 19 images

Comment: It works fine with only 5 images, not a single error

Comment: If you try add mos images what happend?

Comment: it works fine, but if i click the back button and start the class again it stops working

Comment: is because you are not releasing the memory.

Comment: generally assign null to variables.

Comment: sorry but can you give me an example

Comment: Imageview imageview = null; when your fragment or activity finished.

Comment: do i write this in the OnCreate Method, or where exactly should I type it?

Comment: I am really sorry but I don't know how to do what you said. how to make an onFinish() method and how should I type Imageview imageview = null; in it?

Comment: First, try reduce the size of your images.

Comment: I did reduce all of my images, but nothing changed

Comment: The device maybe, if you put a slow memory, could be the reason.